# Date Format when editing asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm facing a problem with the format of the Date when editing. That is my validation parameter:

```
[Required]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime dateIn
```

When entering the date in database (create) the format for ex: 22/02/1998 is correct but when editing, the format it is 22.02.1998.

Even if there is the parameter AppyFormatInEditMode. It seems that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

*Well*, I feel like your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx)'s [`DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) is `.` and `/` replace itself to it

From [`DisplayFormatAttribute.DataFormatString` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.dataformatstring.aspx)

> Use the DataFormatString property to specify a **custom display format**
>   for the values that are displayed in the DynamicField object.

And from [`"/"` Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
>   is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
>   localized date separator is retrieved from the
>   [`DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) property of the **current or specified
>   culture**.

You can try to escape your `/` character like

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd\/MM\/yyyy}",...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work when I try to escape / with backslah